# Python - Get data from <a> tab using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, twitter

```
    <a href="/realDonaldTrump/status/868985285207629825" class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" data-original-title="5:20 PM - 28 May 2017"></a>

url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?
ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
print(link.text, link.get('href'))
```

I have trouble retrieving the 'href' tag from the html. The code works in retrieving all the other 'href' except of the one i wanted which is "/realDonaldTrump/status/868985285207629825". I would like to retrieve the 'data-original-title' tag as well. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Also indentation looks wrong

Comment: indent is different from my code as i have to space out a bit, indent is working fine. I am getting all the href above the one i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'})
for link in links:
    try:
        print(link['href'])
        if link['data-original-title']:
            print(link['data-original-title'])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Hi fam! Thanks for your help, but all i receive was:
https://twitter.com
https://twitter.com
https://twitter.com/search-home
https://twitter.com
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
https://about.twitter.com/
https://support.twitter.com/
http://status.twitter.com/

Comment: It does not output the value i wanted. Thank you for helping!

Comment: print(link['data-original-title'] does not seems to be working). I tried using other method as well bu to no avail. Any suggestion?

Comment: because `'data-original-title'` is not exist however i see it is exist as title so you can change `'data-original-title'` to `'title'`

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful towards a greenhorn! It works really well!